# Pivoting 3 Dates Per Personal-ID to Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (DF1) as such - each Personal-ID will have 3 dates associated w/that ID:

[image: DF1]

[image: DF_ID]

I have created a dataframe (DF_ID) w/1 row for each Personal-ID & Column for Each Respective Date (which is currently blank) and would like load/loop the 3 dates/Personal-ID (DF1) into the respective date columns the final dataframe to look as such:
I am trying to learn python and have tried a number of codinging script to accomplish such as:

```
{for index, row in df_bnp_5.iterrows():
     df_id['Date-1'] = (row.loc[0,'hv_lab_test_dt'])
     df_id['Date-2'] = (row.loc[1,'hv_lab_test_dt'])
     df_id['Date-3'] = (row.loc[2,'hv_lab_test_dt'])
  
for i in range(len(df_bnp_5)) : 
   df_id['Date-1'] = df1.iloc[i, 0], df_id['Date-2'] = df1.iloc[i, 2])}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way.  I created a 'helper' column to arrange the dates for each Personal-ID.

```
import pandas as pd

# create data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Personal-ID': [1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5], 
                   'Date': ['10/01/2019', '12/28/2019', '05/08/2020',
                            '01/19/2020', '06/05/2020', '07/19/2020']})

# change data type
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

# create grouping key
df['x'] = df.groupby('Personal-ID')['Date'].rank().astype(int)

# convert to wide table
df = df.pivot(index='Personal-ID', columns='x', values='Date')

# change column names
df = df.rename(columns={1: 'Date-1', 2: 'Date-2', 3: 'Date-3'})

print(df)

x               Date-1     Date-2     Date-3
Personal-ID                                 
1           2019-10-01 2019-12-28 2020-05-08
5           2020-01-19 2020-06-05 2020-07-19
```